# CKeditor remove extra whitespace at beginning - trim

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor

I am trying to remove the extra whitespaces at the **beginning** and **end** of a text generated by ckeditor but not the whtiespaces between the text itself.

I am ending up with many space at beginning and then the actual text.

so I am trying to write a **trim** function for ckeditor generated text, the traditional trim() not working as the text includes `<p></p> &nbsp;` and sometimes  `<br>` so I couldn't just write a regex.

Example of the generated text

```
<p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><br><br><br><br><br><br>here text begins</p><p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>another line</p><p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>third line </p><p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><strong>fourth line</strong></p><p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><span class="text-huge"><strong>sdsdsdsdsd</strong></span></p><h2><span class="text-huge"><i><strong><u>sdsdsdsdsdsdsd</u></strong></i></span><br><br><br><br><br><br><span class="text-huge"><i><strong><u>csdsdsdsdsdsds</u></strong></i></span><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>&nbsp;</h2>
```

I want to remove every tags until the **here text begins** but this text might vary might be anything,

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, I have managed to sort this issue with a workaround, the idea is:

1- parse the total string we got from the ckeditor `content.getData()` to an HTMLCollection,

2- loop over the html tags and delete any tag that does **NOT** have words by checking the property **textContent**, as soon as the tag has words exit the loop.

3- loop inside the tag that has words in it and convert the string to array of words by splitting `str.split(' ')` and loop over the array and remove each `<br>` or `&nbsp;` until you reach anything other than these tag and entity then exit the loop.

4- you need to go through this process from the beginning of the (total text you got from ckeditor) and from the end.

```
        trimedCkEditorText() {
            let contentStr = this.content.getData();
            // Remove Extra whitespaces at the begining of the text
            contentStr = this.trimedCkEditorTextAt(contentStr, true);

            // Remove Extra whitespaces at the end of the text
            contentStr = this.trimedCkEditorTextAt(contentStr, false);

            return contentStr;
        },
        trimedCkEditorTextAt(contentStr, startOfText) {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(contentStr, "text/html")

            // Check first child 
            while(doc.body.children.length) {
                const index = startOfText ? 0 : doc.body.children.length - 1; 
                const child = doc.body.children[index];
                
                if(child.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
                    // Remove <br> tags
                    while(child.children.length) {
                        const index = startOfText ? 0 : child.children.length - 1; 
                        const grandechild = child.children[index];
                        if(grandechild.localName === 'br') grandechild.remove();
                        else break;
                    }

                    // Remove &nbsp;
                    const childTextArray = child.innerHTML.split(' ');
                    while(childTextArray.length) {
                        const index = startOfText ? 0 : childTextArray.length - 1; 
                        if(childTextArray[index] === '&nbsp;') childTextArray.splice(index, 1);
                        else break;
                    }
                    child.innerHTML = childTextArray.join(' ');
                    break;
                } else {
                    child.remove();
                }
            }

            return doc.body.innerHTML;
        }
```